How to delete windows and install ubuntu
I have an problem on installing ubuntu. I already have an windows. I want to delete my windows and boot ubuntu. I manually allocate the partition. That automattically assign to the system windows boot manager.

Does this answer your question? How to remove Windows 10 OS completely & install Ubuntu?

i am in windows 11. currently Ubuntu allocation was different. i want manual allocation.
